# Theano - Potential Memory Leak

Tags: python-3.x, memory, theano

The following line in my Feed Forward Neural Network computes the L2 regularization term:

```
self.L2_reg = tt.sum([tt.sum(P ** 2) for P in self.params])
```

P is here a usual theano symbolical matrix variable. The memory usage increases constantly during training. The same is true for the L1 norm. However, when I don't apply any elemtwise operation at all there is no memory issue:

```
self.L2_reg = tt.sum([tt.sum(P) for P in self.params])
```

How can that be? I'm using theano 0.9 and Python 3.5 on a Windows machine. Thx for any help.

Comment: perhaps you should post it as a github issue. https://github.com/theano/theano/issues

Answer (score 0):

Theano version 0.9.0 has a known issue of memory leak. As a workaround, you can momentarily fall back to version 0.8.2 which will work right.